# Restore Block.io multisig wallet in Electrum

Tags: wallet-recovery, multi-signature, block.io

I've exported my private keys from Block.io. They're compressed WIF keys (starting with L...).

Additionally I've got the following data from Block.io:

- Address type: P2SH (obviously)
- Redeem script
- Redeem script hex
- Two public keys

I've tried to restore that wallet in Electrum with the information I have. But as far as I understand, Electrum needs extended private keys to restore the wallet, right?

So, is there a way to restore that wallet? Maybe in a different wallet client? I've researched a whole evening but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I knew that but I hadn't enough reputation to comment.

I have found a solution. I've got my BCH today from block.io which was already empty but it had a BTC on the day of fork. 
So what you have to do is:

First of all you should get from security settings of you block.io profile: "Redeem Script Hex", and two private keys. (actually you will have some more strings and values but only these three required to claim your BCH).

After that:

Go to http://www.motelmaya.com/BCH/BCH.html

I know this seems strange and may cause doubts and believe me I wasn't sure too. But the real deal was: getting BCH (I had 0,5 of BTC at block.io wallet) or getting nothing.

So, then:

- Click +TX
  Enter the redeem HEX that you received from block.io in the first box (Address, WIF key or Redeem Script)
- Click on "Advanced options" -> "Network" -> Settings and change the network to "Bitcoin Cash (mainnet)"
- Click New -> Transaction or +TX once more.
- Put in the amount you want to transfer and the address you are sending to (your new BCH wallet I guess - I've used my blockchain.info wallet address), make sure that the fee is not too high (I've entered something like 0.000317
- Click "Submit", you will get a long HEX string. copy it
- Click "Sign", paste the copied string, paste the first private key from the  block.io to the "Private key" field, click "Submit", copy the string.
- Paste the string into the second box (below the "Private key" field), paste the second private key from the block.io, click Submit, copy the output
- Go to "Broadcast", paste the string and click "Submit".

That's it. You will recieve TXid which you will be able to check at https://bitcoincash.blockexplorer.com

Actually all regards should go to [ohad serfaty](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/64264/ohad-serfaty) but I can't comment the post where he advised this method because of low reputation.

Good luck!